# Load a different .bashrc while launching konsole or term from command line

Tags: shell-script, gnome-terminal, bashrc, konsole

Launching console or term from command line will load the default .bashrc. But I want load different configs given options passed to it. As of now the best I can think of is that I may define a function in .bashrc which accepts options and meanwhile keep three config files .bashrc0, .bashrc1 and .bashrc2 to replace .bashrc depends on the option passed.

```
#new term function
nterm (){
    if [ "$#" == "1" ]; then
       if [ "$@" == "option_a" ]; then
          yes | cp $HOME/.bashrc1 $HOME/.bashrc
          term
          yes | cp $HOME/.bashrc0 $HOME/.bashrc
       else if [ "$@" == "option_b" ]; then
          yes | cp $HOME/.bashrc2 $HOME/.bashrc
          term
          yes | cp $HOME/.bashrc0 $HOME/.bashrc
       fi
    else 
       term
    fi
}
```

So I can call

```
$nterm option_a
```

Or

```
$nterm option_b
```

To start two new terminals with different settings loaded. Same with konsole.

But is there an **inherited way** to do so in term/console/bash or **a much more consice and explicit alternative**?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the use of bash's `--rcfile` parameter; it forces interactive bash shells to use the given RC file *instead* of `~/.bashrc`. Change your function to:

```
nterm (){
    if [ "$#" == "1" ]; then
       if [ "$@" == "option_a" ]; then
          term -e bash --rcfile "$HOME/.bashrc1"
       else if [ "$@" == "option_b" ]; then
          term -e bash --rcfile "$HOME/.bashrc2"
       fi
    else 
       term
    fi
}
```

I'm not familiar with the `term` command; I assume from your tags that it's gnome-terminal or a wrapper for it, in which case I'm having it invoke bash with the corresponding RC files.

Comment: haven't exactly used this but `--rcfile` option does the trick, you get an alternative start-up file.